# Is there a German banter site?

Tags: colloquial, resource, online-resource

I'm looking for something like https://www.viedemerde.fr, but in German: full of colloquial usage, swear words, rudeness and banter. It doesn't have to be a website, it can also be a Twitter account or a Facebook page. But the main thing is: it must have tons of funny and irreverent contents, and back-and-forth exchanges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend https://www.der-postillon.com/ Lots of funny content on the whole site and marvellous word-play at the *Newsticker*. The rudeness is in the subtext.

Comment: @Janka Der Postillon and viedemerde are two completely different types of sites.

Answer (score 4):

Making an answer by elaborating my [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47769/is-there-a-german-banter-site#comment115999_47769):

Have you ever heard of [Jodel](https://www.jodel-app.com/)? It is a mobile app that may suit your needs: the base principle is to post anonymously on everyday things using everyday language.

---

About your criteria:

1. > it must have tons of funny and irreverent contents, and back-and-forth exchanges

Have a look for yourself, I find the content pretty random. Besides, the expression is really freed due to anonymity.

2. > full of colloquial usage, swear words, rudeness and banter

It is mostly used by students. Living myself as a foreigner in Germany, I found many words and expressions which I had never understood before, that I could learn and successfully re-use in everyday life.

---

Bonus:

It is city-based so you can instantly have access to different "slangs" of different regions just by changing your settings!

Comment: Interesting answer. I will look that Jodel thing up. On the risk that I might be disappointed...

Comment: Not everyone likes it ;) glad to let you discover something new. The primary goal was to fit OP's criteria

Comment: Well, now I looked it up (installed it, used it a bit): I do not think that Jodel is what would help ToGa to get acquainted with rude language. The site rules to which you have to subscribe is to always be friendly, loving, and positive, and not use rude language. And accordingly, all the German entries I read there were very agreeable (but for the spelling mistakes and uneducated use of punctuation). No chance to learn bad words there, as far as I see.

Comment: It's true that the "good vibes only" rule does not favor insults and banter between members. However, I find it really appropriate on the "colloquial" part of the question. Furthermore, it suits IMHO OP's main criterium: "tons of funny and irreverent contents, and back-and-forth exchanges" (even though the "funny" part can be debated). This is not meant to be the one and only valid answer. Many good resources are surely available, as your own answer shows, and as answerers, it is our role to point them out to the best of our knowledge.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right, it is a good source for finding typical expressions of oral communication written down. If I would have to learn German I definitely would use this (or I may use it for other languages... e.g. French). You will hardly find these ways of expression in books.

Answer (score 3):

Vielleicht helfen dir Bücher?

- Ernest Borneman: Der obszöne Wortschatz der Deutschen. Sex im Volksmund. Rowohlt, Reinbek 1971; Parkland, Köln 2003, ISBN 3-8934-0036-2.
- Hans-Martin Gauger: Das Feuchte und das Schmutzige: Kleine Linguistik der vulgären Sprache. Beck, München 2012, ISBN 978-3-406-62989-1.

Comment: Dürfte ich erfahren, warum jemand findet, die Antwort sei negativ zu bewerten? Der Fragesteller wollte Internet-Quellen, aber solche konnte bisher keiner nennen. Warum sollten Bücher keine Ersatzlösung sein?

Comment: Keine negative Bewertung von mir, aber meine persönliche Erfahrung ist, dass Bücher, die Alltagssprache beschreiben, oft sehr wenig mit der tatsächlichen Alltagssprache zu tun haben (was sicherlich oft auch an regionalen Besonderheiten liegt).

Comment: Ich kenne (grob) Ernest Bornemann. Der Band 1 ist der Nachschlageteil für 'obszöne Wörter', heute vielleicht etwas veraltet. Band 2 ist eine Art Synonymwörterbuch, z.B. alle Wörter für 'Oralverkehr'. Diese sind jedoch nicht gewichtet, man erfährt so nicht, welche Wörter die gängigsten sind. Die Menge des angebotenen Materials ist erschlagend, auf mich wirkt vieles ausgedacht bzw. ephemer.